# display: table-row with multiple layers of rows before table-cell

Tags: css, less, flexbox, css-tables

This is the HTML that I am working within. (PLEASE NOTE: I cannot change the HTML, only the styling).

```
<div class="table">

    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-row-1">
            <div class="table-row-2">
                <div class="table-col">Column 1</div>
                <div class="table-col">Column 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row-1">
            <div class="table-row-2">
                <div class="table-col">Column 1</div>
                <div class="table-col">Column 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-row-1a">
            <div class="table-row-2">
                <div class="table-col">Column 1</div>
                <div class="table-col">Column 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row-1b">
            <div class="table-row-2">
                <div class="table-col">Column 1</div>
                <div class="table-col">Column 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, there are multiple rows containing the actual cells. I am applying `display:table` to the main `div`, `display:table-row` to the first parent row, and then `display:table-cell` to the column cells.

I am unable to use an actual table as I cannot change the HTML.

I am unsure what to apply to the extra row containers to ensure that they aren't affecting the structure of the table.

This code is being used to make a *flexbox grid* which is more structured on larger screens, meaning that the cells within the same column are the same width. If you could suggest another solution other than the table displays, please do, but I have been unable to find another option.

I am working with less.

Comment: From what I can see, I don't think this is doable with CSS tables, as there is no property that can be applied to the row containers to prevent them from affecting the table layout (even if you set `.table-row` to `display: table-row-group`, you still have two more layers of rows to worry about). You'll probably need flexbox, though as I'm not an expert on flexbox someone else will have to provide a solution on that.

Comment: not sure what is your expected result? are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/qc26pqsw/

Comment: @tessa can you please add any wireframe or image that helps us to understand

Comment: Is there any way you can use JavaScript to rearrange the elements?